# I'm using Chrome stable on OSX how to redirect a url

Tags: macos, mac, google-chrome, browser, http

I've just bought the latest 13in Mac Air and I'm trying to get it to redirect from the international Apple store to the Australian one. The url currently is store.apple.com but I want it to always go to store.apple.com/au/

I was hoping I could use the hosts file but that isn't going to work as it's the same ip address for both. Is there some other method that would allow this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to this page(http://store.apple.com/au/browse/open/country_selector) and choose your country.

Or use [Switcheroo](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/switcheroo-redirector/cnmciclhnghalnpfhhleggldniplelbg) extension.

[image]